# 3.5in TFT screen hat and Raspberry Pi 3+b

Tags: gpio, hdmi, screen, hat

I'm trying to understand something about the MPI3508 screen I purchased (https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07DQKQG6X).

I tried powering it via usb and connected a PC in its HDMI input and got it working (the PC started to display on the screen) while the hat was not connected to the gpio of the Pi.

When trying the same setup with a Pi 3+ b, the screen displays a no signal message (screen powered by either external USB or a Pi usb port). When plugging the Pi HDMI output in a screen, I get the Pi desktop.

I do not need the touchscreen function, but my setup cannot allow connecting the screen hat to the pi gpio.

Is there any way I could use the screen without being connected to the gpio of the Pi?

Comment: Try adding `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.  If that doesn't work, try `hdmi_safe=1`.  Documentation about those is here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md